# Fill gap between two lines with color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Here's my code:

```
def region_of_interest(image):
    height = image.shape[0]
    polygons = np.array([
    [(300, height), (1100, height), (600, 400)] #Dimensions of Polygon
    ])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, polygons, 255)
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)
    return masked_image
```

I want to shade the area between the polygon, and I've tried changing the RGB color in the `cv2.fillPoly` line, but that hasn't worked.

I would prefer for the color to be transparent, but a solid gradient is fine too.

Comment: Hi, can you share with us an image to test your code

Comment: It's a part of a larger code that I'm trying to use to detect lane lines when driving.  Here's a link to a picture of a video of what I have so far: https://ibb.co/2crSv2B

Comment: assume you have 4 corners. you can use the fillpoly function on Mat_A which is empty sheet with same channel and depth as the source image Mat_B.  The the resulting semi transparent Mat_C can be achieved by Mat_C= 0.3*Mat_A + 0.7*Mat_B.   This is the only way that i know will work to get the transparent effect from the opencv library.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working code , if the alpha value is one, there would be no transparency if the value is 0 it will be totally black.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
img = cv2.imread("1.jpeg")
height = img.shape[0]
alpha = 0.7 
line1 = ((50,50),(50,200))
img = cv2.line(img,line1[0],line1[1],(0,255,0),2)
line2 = ((100,50),(100,200))
img = cv2.line(img,line2[0],line2[1],(0,255,0),2)

# cv2.rectangle(img,(10,1),(50,100),(0,0,255),3)
# img[1:100, 10:50] = img[1:100, 10:50]*0.5
img[line1[0][1]:line2[1][1], line1[1][0]:line2[1][0]] = img[line1[0][1]:line2[1][1], 
line1[1][0]:line2[1][0]]*alpha

# img = cv2.fillPoly(img, polygons, 255)
cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

you can change it to make it white  instead of black if the alpha is 0 and dark if alpha is 1 by subtracting the pixels by 255 like this

```
img[line1[0][1]:line2[1][1], line1[1][0]:line2[1][0]] = 255-(img[line1[0] 
[1]:line2[1][1], line1[1][0]:line2[1][0]]*alpha)
```